# Address of pointer returned by function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, member

I try to get the address of a pointer that is returned by a class member function:

```
class Test{
    ...
    char* d;
    ...
    char* getData(){
        return d;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I try to get the address of d (assume that *d has a valid value):

```
Test t; 
char** pd = &t.getData();
```

This gives a syntax error and won't compile on VC2010. How can I get the address of the member pointer variable?

Comment: can't you do-> `char** getData(){ return &d; }` , `char** pd = t.getData();`

Comment: Can you post the syntax error you got?

Answer (score 2):

**Short version:** You're trying to take the address of an rvalue, which is illegal.

**Slightly longer version:** When you do `t.getData()`, the `*d` is returned by value. This is easy to forget because most of the time, when you're working with pointers, you don't worry about pass-by-value versus pass-by-reference. You just return the pointer since it's small.

Here,

```
char** pd = &t.getData();
```

the return value of t.getData is a copy of the pointer, and it's an **rvalue**, meaning it's temporary and will cease to exist after the expression ends. You can't take the address of an rvalue for that reason -- it'd be invalid as soon as the statement ends. If you put that address in an lvalue however, it works just fine:

```
Test t;
char* temp = t.getData(); 
char** pd = &temp;
```

That's because now temp is an **lvalue**, and you can take its address.

For what you're trying to do though, you might be better off having `getValue()` return a `char**`.

Comment: +1. What you say is true, and it's well explained. But it may be useful to mention that at the end of your second version, `pd` holds the address of `temp`, not of the original member `t.d`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getData()` function returns a copy of the pointer. If you want to take the address of the original pointer member, you'd have to change it so that it returns a reference to the pointer:

```
char *&getData() { return d; }
```

(Whether returning references to internal pointers and taking their address is a good idea from a design point of view is a different matter.)